# Duplicate rows in a DataFrame based on column values, outputting column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
data = [
    ['item 1', 'Some text', 0.0, 1, 0.25],
    ['item 2', 'Some other text', 0.5, 0.0, 0.0],
    ['item 3', 'Etc.', 0.0, 0.25, 0.0],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['item_name', 'description', 'class1', 'class2', 'class3'])
```

```
print(df)

  item_name      description  class1  class2  class3
0    item 1        Some text     0.0    1.00    0.25
1    item 2  Some other text     0.5    0.00    0.00
2    item 3             Etc.     0.0    0.25    0.00
```

I would like to duplicate each row for each time a value greater 0 is found in columns `class1` to `class3`, outputting `item_name`, `description`, and the `class_name`. Expected result is:

```
  item_name      description    class
0    item 1        Some text   class2
1    item 1        Some text   class3
2    item 2  Some other text   class1
3    item 3             Etc.   class2
```

I managed to get some output that goes into the right direction by using iterrows, however I am only able to access the class value, and not its name:

```
data_transf = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   for col in row.loc['class1':'class3']:
        if col > 0: data_transf.append(
            [row['item_name'],
             row['description'],
             col
            ])

df_new = pd.DataFrame(data_transf, columns=['item_name', 'description', 'class'])
```

```
print(df_new)

  item_name      description  class
0    item 1        Some text   1.00
1    item 1        Some text   0.25
2    item 2  Some other text   0.50
3    item 3             Etc.   0.25
```

The problem is that `col` is a float and I can't find a way to access its index position to retrieve the class name. How can this be achieved? Perhaps there is a more elegant way to do this using built-ins or coprehensions?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative using [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```
(df.melt(id_vars=['item_name', 'description'],var_name='class').
    query("value>0").drop(columns='value'))

  item_name      description   class
1    item 2  Some other text  class1
3    item 1        Some text  class2
5    item 3             Etc.  class2
6    item 1        Some text  class3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by transforming the data frame to long format with `stack` and then filter out values that are greater than 0:

```
# stack and filter
ldf = df.set_index(['item_name', 'description']).stack()[lambda x: x > 0]

# reset index
ldf = ldf.reset_index().drop(0, axis=1).rename(columns={'level_2': 'class'})

print(ldf)

#  item_name      description   class
#0    item 1        Some text  class2
#1    item 1        Some text  class3
#2    item 2  Some other text  class1
#3    item 3             Etc.  class2
```

[Play](https://webruntime.netlify.app/#/Google_108617488638529745626/python/d84abf53.py)

Comment: One liner of the answer `df.set_index(['item_name', 'description']).stack().to_frame('val').query("val>0").reset_index().drop(columns='val')`